# How do I cron-schedule multiple AWS Lambda calls, each with different arguments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, cron

I'm still trying to understand how the pieces might fit together in an AWS workflow for ftp'ing weather forecast files on a daily basis and storing in S3.

I've created a single lambda function that will accept a forecast start time (e.g. 2016-04-21_12Z) and a forecast hour (e.g. 3, 6, 9, etc...), retrieve the file and store it.

Once a day, I would like to be able to call this lambda function, once for each forecast hour - each lambda function retrieves and stores one file.

Of course, I could just set up a Python program on my own machine to generate the launching of each of these, but I would like to be able to do this in an AWS workflow, but I don't understand what tools are available to help me with this.

I understand that "maybe" I could use CloudWatch to generate events periodically, and I suppose I could have one event for each forecast hour, but is there a straightforward mechanism by which I might be able to launch that single Python program that would in turn launch a collection of lambda calls, one for each forecast hour?

I suspect the tools are there, but I'm struggling to connect the dots right now.